# How can I see my progress towards the socratic badge?

Tags: feature-request

I am pretty sure I've asked questions on 100 days at Christainity.SE, and since I have the silver "Inquisitive" badge, I'm pretty sure my question quality is good.  And yet, I don't have the Socratic badge.

How can I see what my question score is, and the number of days I've asked questions, preferably without having to use the data explorer or the API?

Comment: +1 I think they should work on this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't at the moment.

The nearest you'll get is either by counting your questions by hand or using the data explorer, but even these two methods will only get you an approximate value as the badge takes deleted questions into account which you can't see on your profile and aren't returned by the data explorer.

You can get any questions deleted in the last 90 days by ticking the "show recently deleted posts" in your reputation history.